# Is there a way to "select your next badge" to track self-created tags?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, badge-progress

Clicking the cog icon associated to the "*Next tag badge*" on my [LawSE Activity](https://law.stackexchange.com/users/35069/rick) page brings about a pop-up with the option to "*Select your next badge*" and lists available tags for me to track.  So far so good.

However, missing from this list are all the tags I have personally [created](https://data.stackexchange.com/law/query/1352453/tags-created-by-a-specific-user).

**Is there a way for me to track tags I have created?**

As an aside, I can't see that is connected to the number of answers or score per tag as, for example, I can track [breach-of-contract](/questions/tagged/breach-of-contract) via the pop-up which I have [answered once and scored three](https://law.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbreach-of-contract%5D+user%3Ame) whereas with my self-created [citizens-arrest](/questions/tagged/citizens-arrest) I have [scored 18 with my three answers](https://law.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcitizens-arrest%5D+user%3Ame) but it is not an option in the pop-up.

Comment: ^I've just noted my SEDE link hasn't carried over my results. If anyone's interested, my userID is 35069 and it's for my account on LawSE